# using php to keep class active on sub links

Tags: php

I'm after some advice with some php code I'm working on. So i'm working on a site that allows for adding the class active to links when the use lands on that url. I got that bit no problem with the following code:

```
<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/bricks/' ? ' active' : '');?>
```

What i'm not sure on is keeping the link active if any link follows that. For instance, if someone lands on /bricks/page, /bricks/page2 etc etc i want to keep the active class in place. I'm assuming this is possible but my php skills don't stretch that far!

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can use regex to grab `/bricks/` in your URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a regex or the [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

```
<?= preg_match('/(\/bricks\/)/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? ' active' : ''; ?>
```

```
<?= strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/bricks/') !== false ? ' active' : ''; ?>
```